Problem trying to build 32bit kernel with Pi OS Lite 32 on Pi4B hardware
I'm experimental to make some modification that request to rebuild the kernel, and I'm using Pi4B with Pi OS Lite 32bit. After get the kernel source (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/releases/tag/stable_20240124), and trying to build the kernel natively on on the box by following the document (https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html), I've noticed that when trying to make the .config file, I'll always get CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-v8" eventhough I've specified KERNEL=kernel7l in the enviroment variable. And the the following build process also failed, kinda as expected:
  DTCO    arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/sh1106-spi.dtbo
In file included from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/lse.h:5,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/cmpxchg.h:14,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/atomic.h:7,
                 from ./include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h:5,
                 from ./arch/arm64/include/asm/bitops.h:25,
                 from ./include/linux/bitops.h:68,
                 from ./include/linux/log2.h:12,
                 from kernel/bounds.c:13:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h: In function ‘__ll_sc__cmpxchg_double’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:318:38: error: ‘__uint128_t’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘__int128__’?
  318 |  : "=&r" (tmp), "=&r" (ret), "+Q" (*(__uint128_t *)ptr)  \
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:325:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CMPXCHG_DBL’
  325 | __CMPXCHG_DBL(   ,        ,  ,         )
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  DTCO    arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/si446x-spi0.dtbo
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:318:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  318 |  : "=&r" (tmp), "=&r" (ret), "+Q" (*(__uint128_t *)ptr)  \
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:325:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CMPXCHG_DBL’
  325 | __CMPXCHG_DBL(   ,        ,  ,         )
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:318:51: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
  318 |  : "=&r" (tmp), "=&r" (ret), "+Q" (*(__uint128_t *)ptr)  \
      |                                                   ^
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:325:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CMPXCHG_DBL’
  325 | __CMPXCHG_DBL(   ,        ,  ,         )
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  DTCO    arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/smi.dtbo
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h: In function ‘__ll_sc__cmpxchg_double_mb’:
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:318:38: error: ‘__uint128_t’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘__int128__’?
  318 |  : "=&r" (tmp), "=&r" (ret), "+Q" (*(__uint128_t *)ptr)  \
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:326:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CMPXCHG_DBL’
  326 | __CMPXCHG_DBL(_mb, dmb ish, l, "memory")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:318:51: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
  318 |  : "=&r" (tmp), "=&r" (ret), "+Q" (*(__uint128_t *)ptr)  \
      |                                                   ^
./arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic_ll_sc.h:326:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CMPXCHG_DBL’
  326 | __CMPXCHG_DBL(_mb, dmb ish, l, "memory")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  DTCO    arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/smi-dev.dtbo

The getconf LONG_BIT does return value of "32", though uname -a' will tell
Linux pi4b32lite001 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 <b>aarch64</b> GNU/Linux

So, this means it will only land into corss-compile section then? To me, this is like a bug in makefile that, it should check the OS bit instead of CPU architecture to determain what should be the "native" compile.

AFAICT you're running the 64bit kernel + 32bit userland on your Pi4 (that's the default) You can force the 32bit kernel. Remove arm_64bit=1 from config.txt

Thanks for your comment, @Dirk. Hum... just checked the /boot/config.txt, I don't even have arm_64bit option there.


even though I've specified KERNEL=kernel7l

Those instructions from https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html have a problem.
$ cd linux
$ KERNEL=kernel7
$ make bcm2709_defconfig

The second command has no effect because the variable is not being exported, so it is not passed into the execution environment of make.  It should be:
export KERNEL=kernel7

